# What's an easy way to shut down a computer that I'm connected to via RDP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, shutdown, remote-desktop, remote-shutdown

I have a secondary machine on my local network that I usually use via RDP.  Most of the time, it's on 24/7, but there are times when I may want to shut it down from the RDP client machine.  The shutdown and restart options aren't available from the Windows XP start menu when you connect to a machine via RDP, so how can I shut this machine off without actually going to the physical machine?  Also note that this computer currently doesn't have a monitor attached to it, which is partly why I want to be able to shut it down over RDP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would start a command prompt and type the following command:

**"shutdown -s"** to shutdown in less than a minute.

**"shutdown -f"** to shutdown immediately.

If you really only want to restart, type the following:

**"shutdown -r"**.

Comment: afaik, shutdown -f won't shutdown immediately, it will just kill everything in 60 seconds regardless of whether it quits gracefully. for an instant shutdown you need to do `shutdown -s -f -t 0`.

Comment: If you want to do these actions immediately, add `-t 0` to the command. Or change the 0 to the number of seconds before it happens. Defaults to 30.

Comment: Technically shutdown -f does make the machine shutdown immediately as if you clicking the shutdown button in the start menu. Shutdown -f is initiating the shutdown command. Yes I could have went into extensive details on all of the option with the shutdown command, but he only asked about shutting down and restarting. He didn't ask about everything else. I like my answers to be quick, easy, and direct.

Comment: @David That is not the case on Windows 7 or Vista then. Passing in -f will still cause it to wait 30 seconds. I suspect it is the same with XP as well, but don't have a machine to try it on.

Comment: @vcsjones I thought it had changed too. It hasn't... I tested it on a space machine at my work. The T60 Lenovo Laptop shutoff immediately as if I pressed the power button on the start menu. So trust e, I tested it. If you don't believe me, try it. :)

Comment: @David I was talking about using shutdown from the command line, not using the start menu since there is no start menu option to shut down over remote desktop.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, the easiest way is via the `Shutdown` command from the command prompt or the run box.

If this is a domain and you have the privilage to shut down remotely, you can always use the `shutdown` command from your machine using `Shutdown /s /m \\computername`, or `shutdown -i` for a interactive prompt.
[image]

Lastly, if you do want to it via a normal GUI, next time you are connected, click on the option "Windows Security", this will bring you the traditional <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> prompt, where you can shutdown, restart or do whatever you want to the computer!

(You can also right click on the taskbar and choose `Task Manager` and do it from there).

Answer (score 2):

From `Start` -> `Run...` you can run `shutdown -s`. From a command prompt, you can execute `shutdown /?` to see a list of options.

Comment: This would have been a good comment under the original answer that states the same thing other than the "shutdown /?"

Comment: @David: When I wrote that answer, there were no other answers. I saw the notice that another answer had been posted just as I was about to post mine, so I just went ahead and hit the Post button.

Comment: @garyjohn7 That's fine. :) Great minds think alike...

Answer (score 1):

I go to the desktop and do Alt+F4. That will give you the options to shutdown, restart or logoff.